# Python: Making sure a string is a valid input by user, and rejecting any other input

Tags: python

Trying to configure my program so that it will only accept answers 'yes' and 'no' only throughout my program, and any other inputs like integers and other strings would produce faulty messages.  using .isalpha() is not working for me either, Any tips on how to help with code would be appreciated.

```
text = True

    if text:
        textHelp = input('Are you sleeping? '.isalpha())
        if textHelp == 'yes':
            print('Cannot take phone call b/c im sleeping')
        else:
            print('Can take phone call)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like with if..elif..else:

```
if textHelp == 'yes':
    print('Cannot take phone call b/c im sleeping')
elif textHelp == 'no':
    print('Can take phone call')
else:
   print("Faulty message")
```

If you want to keep prompt continue on invalid input:

```
while True:
  if textHelp == 'yes':
    print('Cannot take phone call b/c im sleeping')
    break
  elif textHelp == 'no':
    print('Can take phone call')
    break
  else:
   print("Faulty message")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```py
while true:
    textHelp = input('Are you sleeping? ')
    if textHelp.isalpha():
        # your expected output ...
        break
    else:
        print("try again!")
```

But I think the answer of @WasifHasan is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, what you're looking for is something like this:

```py
input_text = input('Are you sleeping? ').lower()

if input_text == 'yes':
  print('Cannot take phone call b/c im sleeping')
elif input_text == 'no':
  print('Can take phone call')
else:
  print('Expected a yes or a no for an answer')
```

Thr `.lower()` method ensures that "Yes", "yes", "yEs" etc. are treated the same. You do not need the `.isalpha()` method for this scenario.

Comment: This can of course be put inside a loop to run it until you get "yes" or "no" as the input